# DeserializeObject from json string not getting value

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

i have a json file i want to Json to  Deserialize all Object but it return noting when it deserialized in my program

**Json string**

```
{


 "routes": {
    "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20-20170324": {
      "id": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20-20170324",
      "revision": 457,
      "date": "20170324",
      "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
      "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
      "steps": [
        {
          "type": "departure",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 0,
          "startSec": 0,
          "endSec": 7200,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": ""
        },
        {
          "type": "pickup",
          "orderId": "cd0711f2-f43e-48e9-97db-d76822fbcd54",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 8460,
          "startSec": 8460,
          "endSec": 9000,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": "1.1",
          "trackingData": {
            "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
            "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
            "timeInSec": 8460,
            "timeInLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "timeOutSec": 9000,
            "timeOutLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "status": "done",
            "statusSec": 8761,
            "statusLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "timeInDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeInDetectedLatLng": null,
            "timeOutDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeOutDetectedLatLng": null,
            "pods": null
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "delivery",
          "orderId": "cd0711f2-f43e-48e9-97db-d76822fbcd54",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 9060,
          "startSec": 9060,
          "endSec": 9120,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": "1.2",
          "trackingData": {
            "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
            "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
            "timeInSec": 9060,
            "timeInLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "timeOutSec": 9120,
            "timeOutLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "status": "done",
            "statusSec": 9314,
            "statusLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "timeInDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeInDetectedLatLng": null,
            "timeOutDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeOutDetectedLatLng": null,
            "pods": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "orders": {},
  "vehicles": {},
  "depots": {},
  "drivers": {}
}
```

I created this class for desalinized

```
 public class CurrentRoutes
{
    public class TrackingData
    {
        public string driverId { get; set; }
        public string vehicleId { get; set; }
        public int timeInSec { get; set; }
        public List<int> timeInLatLng { get; set; }
        public int timeOutSec { get; set; }
        public List<int> timeOutLatLng { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int statusSec { get; set; }
        public List<int> statusLatLng { get; set; }
        public int timeInDetectedSec { get; set; }
        public object timeInDetectedLatLng { get; set; }
        public int timeOutDetectedSec { get; set; }
        public object timeOutDetectedLatLng { get; set; }
        public object pods { get; set; }
    }

    public class Step
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int idleTimeSec { get; set; }
        public int perStopTimeSec { get; set; }
        public int arrivalSec { get; set; }
        public int startSec { get; set; }
        public int endSec { get; set; }
        public int driveToNextSec { get; set; }
        public int distanceToNextMt { get; set; }
        public string displayLabel { get; set; }
        public string orderId { get; set; }
        public TrackingData trackingData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Orders
    {
    }

    public class Vehicles
    {
    }

    public class Depots
    {
    }

    public class Drivers
    {
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Routes routes { get; set; }
        public Orders orders { get; set; }
        public Vehicles vehicles { get; set; }
        public Depots depots { get; set; }
        public Drivers drivers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Routes
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int revision { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string vehicleId { get; set; }
        public string driverId { get; set; }
        public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
    }



}
```

and my code in c# in below code i am passing json in pikdelresponse

```
CurrentRoutes.RootObject rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentRoutes.RootObject>(pikdelresponse);
```

can you please advice me how can i get the value for above json. Thanks for you comments and code.

Comment: The problem you have here is that you have a key called `3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20-20170324`, is that accurate?

Comment: @DavidG thanks for your response. The key you are talking about every time changed when i get request. You can understand per request the id will be change .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `Dictionary<string, Route>`. For example:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Route> Routes { get; set; }
    public Orders orders { get; set; }
    public Vehicles vehicles { get; set; }
    public Depots depots { get; set; }
    public Drivers drivers { get; set; }
}

public class TrackingData
{
    public string driverId { get; set; }
    public string vehicleId { get; set; }
    public int timeInSec { get; set; }
    public List<int> timeInLatLng { get; set; }
    public int timeOutSec { get; set; }
    public List<int> timeOutLatLng { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int statusSec { get; set; }
    public List<int> statusLatLng { get; set; }
    public int timeInDetectedSec { get; set; }
    public object timeInDetectedLatLng { get; set; }
    public int timeOutDetectedSec { get; set; }
    public object timeOutDetectedLatLng { get; set; }
    public object pods { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int idleTimeSec { get; set; }
    public int perStopTimeSec { get; set; }
    public int arrivalSec { get; set; }
    public int startSec { get; set; }
    public int endSec { get; set; }
    public int driveToNextSec { get; set; }
    public int distanceToNextMt { get; set; }
    public string displayLabel { get; set; }
    public string orderId { get; set; }
    public TrackingData trackingData { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int revision { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string vehicleId { get; set; }
    public string driverId { get; set; }
    public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(pikdelresponse);
```

Comment: Thanks this works You Rocks. i am upvoting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
"3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20-20170324": {

}
```

your json should be like this

```
{


 "routes": {
      "id": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20-20170324",
      "revision": 457,
      "date": "20170324",
      "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
      "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
      "steps": [
        {
          "type": "departure",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 0,
          "startSec": 0,
          "endSec": 7200,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": ""
        },
        {
          "type": "pickup",
          "orderId": "cd0711f2-f43e-48e9-97db-d76822fbcd54",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 8460,
          "startSec": 8460,
          "endSec": 9000,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": "1.1",
          "trackingData": {
            "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
            "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
            "timeInSec": 8460,
            "timeInLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "timeOutSec": 9000,
            "timeOutLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "status": "done",
            "statusSec": 8761,
            "statusLatLng": [
              28550470,
              -81211578
            ],
            "timeInDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeInDetectedLatLng": null,
            "timeOutDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeOutDetectedLatLng": null,
            "pods": null
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "delivery",
          "orderId": "cd0711f2-f43e-48e9-97db-d76822fbcd54",
          "idleTimeSec": 0,
          "perStopTimeSec": 0,
          "arrivalSec": 9060,
          "startSec": 9060,
          "endSec": 9120,
          "driveToNextSec": -1,
          "distanceToNextMt": -1,
          "displayLabel": "1.2",
          "trackingData": {
            "driverId": "f8ddf3fc-8e70-4edd-b0b4-5e41cf86d72a",
            "vehicleId": "3d3d6f6c-5d05-4a4e-a17e-1b128df78c20",
            "timeInSec": 9060,
            "timeInLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "timeOutSec": 9120,
            "timeOutLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "status": "done",
            "statusSec": 9314,
            "statusLatLng": [
              28472604,
              -81398655
            ],
            "timeInDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeInDetectedLatLng": null,
            "timeOutDetectedSec": -1,
            "timeOutDetectedLatLng": null,
            "pods": null
          }
        }
      ]
  },
  "orders": {},
  "vehicles": {},
  "depots": {},
  "drivers": {}
}
```

and it will be ok, or change your class/object tree declaration like this

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public Dictionary<string,Routes> routes { get; set; }
            public Orders orders { get; set; }
            public Vehicles vehicles { get; set; }
            public Depots depots { get; set; }
            public Drivers drivers { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: i can't remove this because the json are sending from different server to us and i need to use this as a my request id

Comment: ok, i have changed answer above, look it , change yout public class RootObject like this
        public class RootObject
        {
            public Dictionary<string,Routes> routes { get; set; }
            public Orders orders { get; set; }
            public Vehicles vehicles { get; set; }
            public Depots depots { get; set; }
            public Drivers drivers { get; set; }
        }

Comment: and use routes values